# How calculate working time in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How calculate working time eg.

7.5 = 7h and 30 min (working hours)

0.75 = 45 min  (pause)

8 = 8h (Planing hours)

How get result eg. (-15 min) below query return 00:15 is it possible get in minus or use have better example?

```
Select
      to_char(time'0:0:0'+numtodsinterval((7.5 + 0.75 - 8 ),'hour'),'hh24:mi')
from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arithmetic backwards and to get a negative number you want `8 - (7.5 + 0.75)`.

Don't use a time and just use the interval (and extract the sign, hour and minute components using string functions if you want a different format):

```sql
SELECT numtodsinterval(8 - (7.5 + 0.75),'hour') AS interval,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         numtodsinterval(8 - (7.5 + 0.75),'hour'),
         '([+-]?)(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+\.?\d*)',
         '\1\3:\4'
       ) AS hhmm
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| INTERVAL | HHMM |
| --- | --- |
| -000000000 00:15:00.000000000 | -00:15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YwXc1eDe)